# Right to Left Direction in WPS Office Writer?

Tags: linux, right-to-left, wps

How to change text direction from L2R to R2L in WPS office for Persian/Parsi or Arabic languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the home tab, at the end, click `Settings > Paragraph`.
A dialog box will open up with the right-to-left option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found the R2L option where you mentioned. I hope it gets it own button like other office apps. Very confusing.

Comment: You are welcome, you should accept the answer then!

Comment: I just selected the checkmark. Is it what you meant?