# Sheet Right to left in WPS Spreadsheets

Tags: right-to-left, arabic, wps-spreadsheet

I would like to know how to change **sheet direction from L2R to R2L** in WPS office **(Spreadsheets)** for Arabic language?

The option is in Page Layout in MS Excel, but I can't seem to find it in WPS.

[Page Layout in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pOhs.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right to Left Direction in WPS Office Writer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1674291/right-to-left-direction-in-wps-office-writer)

Comment: Thanks, But no. the question isn't about text align, but the whole sheet, as you can see in the screen attached. this option is available in Ms Excel, and is easily applied. I can't find similar option in WPS.